# Android use component name to launch an activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-activity, components

There are many ways to start another activity.
The most of the overloading methods requires you to pass a context.

But when using componentName to launch an activity using

```
public Intent setComponent (ComponentName component)
```

and this constructor for ComponentName

```
ComponentName(String pkg, String cls)
```

You see above, I am able to launch an activity WITHOUT using any Context argument

But it must use some "context" somehow internally, am I right? If so, which context? Application one or the activity one?
Does this mean that every time I use this two methods (above), I do not need to worry about memory leak becuase I am not passing any context around??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to worry about memory leaks in either case, but it's good that you're keeping an eye on where you're passing Context objects. Intent simply uses the Context parameter to look up your package name when you use the [`Intent(Context, Class)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) constructor or [`setClass(Context, Class)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) method. They're just convenience methods.

Answer (score 5):

adamp's answer is correct (he got to it before I could post).

Just to expand on it this is the source for the `Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)` constructor...

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

...and this is the source for `ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls)` constructor

```
public ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls) {
    mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();
    mClass = cls.getName();
}
```

As adamp implies, the `Intent` methods that take a `Context` are convenience methods that only use it to create the `ComponentName` which in turn only deals in `String` types (`mPackage` and `mClass`). Neither the `Intent` nor the `ComponentName` hold a reference to the `Context`.

Comment: Thanks MisterSquoink! I would have accepted both of your answers if i am allowed to.  but anyway, thank you for your source code.. it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

`startActivity()` does not require a context as a parameter; it's a method within a class which is already derived from (or implements) Context. That is -- you cannot call `startActivity()` if you do not have a Context from which to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand your question. But you do not use context when you defining intents. You use context to call components using intents. For instance, you use:

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```

But usually you call these methods inside your Activities and Services, that extends Context. Thus, you simply use:

```
startActivity(intent)
```